# MPMoviePlayerController play video from url with proxy authen

Tags: iphone, authentication, proxy, mpmovieplayercontroller

I develop an application that can play video(.mp4) via http. According to many tutorials ,they suggest me to use MPMoviePlayerController. In my workplace, I have to do a proxy server authentication to access the internet but I can't find any example code to do a proxy authen with MPMoviePlayerController so I can't play any video via http.

Do you guys have any suggestions?

Thanks,
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a solution from Apple Document

NSURLCredential *credential = [[NSURLCredential alloc]
                                   initWithUser: @"myusername"
                                   password: @"mypassword"
                                   persistence: NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];

```
NSURLProtectionSpace *protectionSpace = [[NSURLProtectionSpace alloc]
                                     initWithProxyHost:@"192.168.110.14" //proxy server
                                         port:8080 
                                         type:NSURLProtectionSpaceHTTPProxy 
                                         realm:nil 
                                         authenticationMethod:NSURLAuthenticationMethodDefault];
[[NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage]
 setDefaultCredential: credential
 forProtectionSpace: protectionSpace];
[protectionSpace release];
[credential release];
```